# SQL Server date column sorting dates automatically

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting, date

I have a table with a date column. I am inserting dates in that column using a `DateTimePicker` in C#.

Everything works fine. But I want the dates inserted in the table to be ordered. Currently when I add today's date in one row and then add yesterday's date or any past date, it gets added in the 2nd row ofc.

I want that to be added in 1st row instead. Before today's date, to make all the dates in order.

Is there any property of the date column I can use to ensure the dates order?

Comment: There is no such thing as ordered table. If you need specific order use `SELECT * FROM tab_name ORDER BY date_column`. And yes, clustered index won't help either, because query optimizer can read data in any order, especially when parallelism is involved.

Comment: Hi @sedate , can you show us your steps, please?

Comment: Try this simple query on your date attribute: select date from table  ORDER BY date desc;

Comment: Always have an order by clause - you need to stop thinking of it as "optional" and start thing of it as "customer requirement".

Comment: @AndyK I have created a table in sql and I am using windows forms to insert rows in the table including dates using datetimepicker. I added some record fine but When I selected a date from previous month, it got added but it was in the last row.
This thing was disturbing my 'last 5 days record selection'. I was thinking if maybe there is a way to order the dates but I guess there is no way.

Comment: @Sedate, this might be an [XY Problem] (http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/311071)... What you describe shows clearly that you have to dive into the basics of SQL and databases. Maybe rethink your problem and start a new question where you describe your problem (What do I try to achieve?). "The last five records" is never a question of "just taking the bottom five rows"...

Answer (score 2):

There is **absolutely NO implicit order** in SQL Server datatables! No index, no clustered index, no trick... A simple `SELECT * FROM table` may come back with sorted data - or not...

If you need your data sorted in a special way you must add an `ORDER BY`

Now one solution for your problem:

Create an updateable VIEW (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180800.aspx) on your table which is ordered like you want it. Than commuicate through this view...

Important is: Even when you specify `SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT * FROM YourTable ORDER BY YourColumn` the VIEW would **not** come back with sorted data...

The trick here is to introduce the sorting with a ROW_NUMBER()

I took for testing one of my tables. To make it more difficult I took one with an IDENTITY column.

And please keep in mind: The only **sure** order is the **outermost ORDER BY**

```
CREATE VIEW vwOneTableWithIdentityID
AS
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SortColumn) AS OrderedInx
      ,* FROM OneTableWithIdentityID
GO

SELECT * FROM vwOneTableWithIdentityID;
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT OneTableWithIdentityID ON;
INSERT INTO vwOneTableWithIdentityID(OneTableWithIdentityIDID,AnotherID,SortColumn) VALUES(-5,1081,'aabc');
SET IDENTITY_INSERT OneTableWithIdentityID OFF;
GO

SELECT * FROM vwOneTableWithIdentityID
GO

DELETE FROM vwOneTableWithIdentityID WHERE OneTableWithIdentityIDID=-5;
GO

SELECT * FROM vwOneTableWithIdentityID;
GO

DROP VIEW vwOneTableWithIdentityID;
```

Comment: "If you need your data sorted in a special way you must add an ORDER BY"
Should I add an ORDER BY in my Insert Query?

Comment: Views are inherently unordered as you cannot specify an ORDER BY clause in it. I don't understand why you then say *Create an updateable VIEW on your table which is **ordered** like you want it.*

Comment: @Sedate, No! It is of absolutely no influence what you do on your inserts. The only point where sorting makes a difference is when you read your data...

Comment: @TT, Just try this :-) If you introduce the ordering with a ROW_NUMBER()  you'll get a sorted result. But I'm already thinking of deleting this answer...

Comment: Is that behaviour documented? If so I'd love to see that link.

Comment: @TT, If you look at the "General Remarks" here https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-at/library/ms186734.aspx this could be reversely interpreted as: Yes. But to be honest: I would not use this  myself... Still it might be an approach in specialised circumstances... I used this before to create sorted sub-selects together with FOR XML and encountered no problems up to now.

Comment: That would be true **IF** values in the `SortColumn` are unique. You should put that in bold and with lots of exclamantion marks.

Comment: @TT, don't be academic :-) This is **always** true. Even with a regular ORDER BY clause you have no guaranteed order, if you state a non-unique column to sort after...

Answer (score 0):

The physical order of a record is dependent on CLUSTER INDEX.
if you want DBMS order your data physically without

```
  ORDER BY
```

clauses, create a clustered index on the field you want.